# How to ignore MS Access error 2113 totally?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a textBox formatted as "Short Date". When I put invalid data in field, for example random "dfsdf", and try to change focus, form throws validation Error 2113.
My goal is to give an opportunity to user to close form by click on "Cancel" button without any problem, because no matter what he entered in Date textbox while form is canceled.

I can handle this error and disable message with Form_Error event, but focus stays set to date textBox anyway, when i try to click Cancel button, and button is never clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I use a setup, probably similar to yours:

```
Private Sub Form_Error(DataErr As Integer, Response As Integer)

    Const InvalidDate   As Long = 2113

    Select Case DataErr
        Case InvalidDate
            MsgBox "Invalid date!"
            Response = acDataErrContinue
            ' Cancel invalid entry.
            Me.Undo
            ' DoCmd.Close
        Case Else
            Response = acDataErrDisplay
    End Select

End Sub
```

Problem is, that this will fire before your button gets focus. This means, that the form doesn't even know what you clicked, only that it was somewhere outside the date textbox.

Thus, the `DoCmd.Close` would close the form for whatever was clicked.

You may turn it into an advantage, that the user is able to watch the removal of the faulty input ...

Answer (score 0):

You should use the after update event to check if the user entered a valid date, 
if not then clear or undo. Without knowing the controls of your form i can't tell if you allow users to change table values or if you are using transactions.
pseudo code:

```
Private Sub Text1_AfterUpdate()
   If Check_If_Date Then
      Execute_Code
   Else
   End If
End Sub

Private Function Check_If_Date() as Boolean
   If IsDate(Text1) then
      Check_If_Date = True
   Else
      Check_If_Date = False
      Select Case msgbox("Not a valid date", vbOKCancel)
         case vbOK
            reset_value
         case vbCancel
            Close_Form
         case else
      End Select
   End If
End Sub

Private Sub Reset_Value()
   'need to clear value or undo 
End Sub

Public Sub Execute_Code()
   'Code to save values or allow Update to complete
End Sub

Private Sub Close_Form()
   'Code For Closing Form and logging errors
End Sub
```

I split up repeatable actions for reuse in case the same thing can be repeated in another text box for example a second date or to get the same behavior for the other controls.